# Accessing generic object parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generics

Consider the following snippet:

```
public class FooRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T>
    where T : EntityBase
{
    public FooRepository(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
        : base(sessionFactory)
    {
        this.AfterWriteOperation += (sender, local) => this.Log();
    }

    public void Log()
    {
        // I want to access T here
    }
}
```

I want to access `T` inside the `Log()` function but the problem is that I can't change the constructor signature, like: `FooRepository(ISessionFactory sessionFactory, T entity)`. I don't know how to pass it into `Log()`.

Is there another way?

**UPDATE**:

I want to access the instance of `T` inside `Log()`.

**UPDATE 2**:

Well, sorry for the mess. I'm not used to all this stuff. I will try to clarify things here. So my repository is called in the Service layer:

```
BarRepository.Update(entityToPersist); // Bar inherits from Foo
```

Inside the `Update` method the event `AfterWriteOperation` is called:

```
if (AfterWriteOperation != null)
    AfterWriteOperation(this, e);
```

With all those things I just let away the simple fact that `e` in above case is my entity, so I can pass it to Log this way:

```
(sender, local) => this.Log(local); // I will rename local to entity
```

And get it inside the method.

Comment: What does *access `T`* mean? `typeof(T)`? Otherwise just use it...

Comment: @ta.speot.is like `void Log(T entity)` and use it inside the method.

Comment: Well, then write that then? Why is that not an option? Did you try declaring `Log` like that? Taking a parameter of type `T`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You mean just using it? When I try I get `Type parameter name is not valid at this point`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I can't figure out how to access it inside the constructor to pass it to `Log()`.

Comment: Regarding your update: What instance of `T` are you talking about? I don't see any instances of `T`.

Comment: Do you *have* something from `AfterWriteOperation` that you want to log?

Answer (score 4):

> like `void Log(T entity)` and use it inside the method.

[Well just do that](http://ideone.com/1UO2Of):

```
using System;

namespace Works4Me
{
    public interface ISessionFactory { }
    public class EntityBase { }
    public class BaseRepository<T> where T : EntityBase { }

    public class FooRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T>
        where T : EntityBase
    {
        public FooRepository(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
        {
        }

        public void Log(T entity)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
        // your code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

> Success   #stdin #stdout 0.01s 33480KB

With regards to your other statement:

> I want to access the instance of `T` inside `Log()`.

`T` in and of itself has no instance. You get can the `Type` object representing `T` with `typeof(T)`.

Comment: Well, now I could get the instance, by it was my fault all the time. Thank you for your time. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get information about the type e.g. `Name`, `Methods`, `Interfaces`, `...` then use `typeof(T`) in `log` - thats like the `.GetType()` call on an instance and will return the type of the generic parameter. 
If you want to work with any instance of the type, you have to

a) create an instance `(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)))` or

b) pass the instance via the constructor and then to the `this.Log(passedInstance)` call.

Comment: Strange that it worked partially. I got the instance with the **b**  option, but is haves all the properties with `null` values.

Comment: and the instance you pass is has values at those properties?

Comment: I don't see the problem. You cant fire an event in a class where it is not defined - actually there is no need for the event since log is also part of the same class-hierarchy? For me your code works...